# how to check and alert the user if the session object's capacity exceeds the memory 

Tags: memory, session

hi i was working on a application developed in asp & c#.net, i want alert the usersif the session capacity exceeds the memory  limit. how can i alert the user if the session object's capacity exceeds the  memory .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no per-session memory limit, unless you come up with one. Of course there is the overall memory limit and you can check the overall memory consumption using `GC.GetTotalMemory` method